# How do I simulate ctrl + J to open the download tab using jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to use a button to open the download tab by simulating the ctrl + j shortcut

so far I tried

```
var event = jQuery.Event("keydown");
event.ctrlKey = true;
event.which = 74; // Key code for 'J'
$(document).trigger(event);
```

Comment: Are you in a browser extension? If you are just in a webpage, no, you cannot do any of that - just imagine if you could just navigate somebody else's system by simulating keyboard events. What a nightmare. Events have a `isTrusted` property, and if you generate events yourself, they can never be `true`. Not that it matters, events in the browser don't bubble up to the system/application anyway.